# как переназначить кнопку "последние приложения"

Tags: java, android, key

Например если в манифесте в нужной активити указать:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

то эта активити будет открываться по нажатию на кнопку HOME....

как сделать, чтоб активити открывалась по нажатию на кнопку "последние приложения"

это первая из трёх кнопок, не знаю её keyCode

но вторая это HOME
а третья BACK

вот пример как я могу отловить BACK:

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        event.startTracking();
        Log.i("КП", "нажали на кп назад");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

может так же и нажатие на "последние приложения" можно сделать?
какой у неё keyCode вообще....

так... решил через "специальные возможности" сделать, вот сам сервис :

```
public class SpecialService extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {

}




@Override
protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();


        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            Log.d("Check", "KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP");
    
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            Log.d("Check", "KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN");
           
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            Log.d("Check", "KEYCODE_MENU");
            
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH) {
            Log.d("Check", "KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH");
           
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ALL_APPS) {
            Log.d("Check", "KEYCODE_ALL_APPS");
          
        }





    return super.onKeyEvent(event);
}




}
```

KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP и KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN работают, остальные нет (там всевозможные варианты перечислил на всякий, дабы узнать)

Answer (score 1):

Кнопка называется [меню](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_MENU).

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
   if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
       // Сюда добавляете свой код
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: пробовал, не работает, ноль реакции

Comment: и KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH пробовал